# openni doesn't find kinect

Tags: kinect, openni, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and ROS Groovy.

lsusb shows the kinect:

```
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 002 Device 018: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

But when I run roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch, it doesn't find the kinect.

```
[ INFO] [1357079636.178559036]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1357079639.179093142]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

A week ago, after installing the updated openni package, everything worked and now I get the same "no devices connected" message even though I tried connecting it in different usb ports etc. Is this a bug or is my camera somehow broken?

Regards,

Oier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51286/openni-doesn%27t-find-kinect/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2013-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, after trying everything from manually putting the devices id on the launcher file, to remove gspca_kinect (which wasn't loaded), I had the brilliant idea of reinstalling all the openni ros packages via synaptic, now it works :-)

---

Originally posted by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) with karma: 145 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-04**:
I'm having similar issues and tried re-installing all the openni packages via synaptic, but when I went to re-install them it appears there are only 32bit version available at the moment. Did you have this problem? I'll try again tomorrow but it appears there is a debian issue.

**Comment by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on 2013-01-04**:
What version of Ubuntu are you using? I have 12.10 and the openni packages installed are 64 bits architecture.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-10**:
I'm on 12.04. The packages are available again - not sure if it was my computer or the servers.

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2013-02-04**:
I updated on electric (ros-electric-openni-kinect (0.3.4-s1336532617~lucid => 0.3.6-s1356576176~lucid)) and it broke everything. I got the "No Device Connected" error, I reinstalled and it fixed it.